# How would I properly insert this PHP into an <a> tag's title?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I know this code isn't correct, but I would like to inject the HTML and PHP into the title of the below  tag.

```
<p class="related_articles" title="<a href='<?php the_field(related_articles_1_link); ?>' target="_blank"><?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_title); ?></a>"Related Articles</p>
```

I am using a jQuery tooltip plugin (http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) that grabs content from the title tag and displays it as the tooltip content. I have Advanced Custom Fields setup (WordPress plugin) that allows me to publish custom field content. In effect, the content I post in these custom fields will end up in the tooltip.

My goal is to produce a tooltip when the user hovers over "Related Articles", that displays a link that is clickable. Again, the above jQuery tooltip plugin grabs the content from the title, which is why this is causing difficulty

Comment: What HTML code you want to get? Add example to your code.

Comment: You want to put a link inside your title???

Comment: I believe even if you put a link in an anchor title, it will do nothing

Comment: the tooltip I am using (I edited my original post) grabs content from the title

Comment: Why do you need to put the link in the tooltip? What link will it be? Usually the element, that produces the tooltip is linkable. This kind of code will not get validated and also it most likely will not work in most of the browsers. Rather tell us, what is the higher goal and we can give you an alternative.

Comment: @ Kalle H. Väravas - thanks for the response. Essentially I am looking for the tooltip, when hovered over, to produce a little box with 3 relate article links. So, the tooltip will in fact display content that can be interacted with, and will not be used as a normal tooltip where it usually displays warnings or more info.

Comment: Well, then look for such jQuery plugin. That's basically either hover and then display preloaded container OR you can load the hover-boxes content via AJAX. That's very simple jQuery. If you would learn a little and try something.. I guess you don't have to make a new question for it, but if I would be you, I would format the question: This is what I got so far. Its not good, is there any alternatives? -- In that way you are showing some effort, but some good person will give you the right code. Anyways, are the articles preloaded or you want to use AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as we understand what you are trying to do. Lets get some things clear.

```
<p class="related_articles" title="<a href='<?php the_field(related_articles_1_link); ?>' target="_blank"><?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_title); ?></a>"Related Articles</p>
```

Is SO wrong on so many levels. First of all things, its not valid in any way. Second of all, you are not ending your `<a>`. You are also missing one echo and `target=""`, inside `title=""` was not escaped: `target=\"\"`.

So in a nutshell to straight up answer your question, this maybe will work (maybe, because its seriously uncommon and nonstandard)

```
<p class="related_articles" title="<a href=\"<?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_link); ?>\" target=\"_blank\"><?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_title); ?></a>">Related Articles</p>
```

Also, as one of the users already mentioned. If your server server enables [short open tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag), then you could make the `<?php echo $foo; ?>` shorter: `<?= $foo ?>`. So in your codes case it would look like:

```
<p class="related_articles" title="<a href=\"<?= the_field(related_articles_1_link) ?>\" target=\"_blank\"><?= the_field(related_articles_1_title) ?></a>">Related Articles</p>
```

**However**, as probably mentioned already. This is not recommended method and may produce all sort of issues. I recommend to research for a better solution.

Comment: yeah....I think I need a better solution. I tried everyone's and I it doesn't seem to want to draw the jQuery tooltip for me.

Comment: @Brian Reformat your question as I mentioned in above comment and give this question about a hour. You will surely get your solution or at least the base of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the short form if your server supports it:

`<?=the_field(related_articles_1_link)?>`

or else, you should echo it:

`<?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_link); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this is what you want?

```
<p class="related_articles">
    Related Articles:
    <a href="<?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_link); ?>" target="_blank">
        <?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_title); ?>
    </a>
</p>
```

---

Now that you've clarified that your question was regarding the [jQuery Tooltip plugin](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/slide.html), you should do the following:

```
<p class="related_articles">Related Articles</p>

<a class="tooltip" href="<?php the_field(related_articles_1_link); ?>" target="_blank">
    <?php echo the_field(related_articles_1_title); ?>
</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.related_articles').tooltip();
```

The reason this works:

The tooltip plugin looks at the element right after the one which `.tooltip()` was applied to. If that next element has a class name of `tooltip`, it'll use that as the contents of the tooltip (instead of the title attribute).

Comment: I think he wants <P> tag with tooltip and a clickable link in it.

Comment: Well, unless he wants to make a javascript tooltip, that's impossible.

Comment: @Joseph Silber the tooltip I am using (I edited my original post) grabs content from the title=""

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="related_articles" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<a href="'. the_field(related_articles_1_link) .'">'. the_field(related_articles_1_title) .'</a>'); ?>">Related Articles</p>
```

While this should work, I am not sure if your mentioned jQuery plugin is able to interpret the given html in a title attribute as HTML (you need to test it). Most likely this will be interpreted as text and all tags will be visible to the end user, but this is not what you want.

I found an example of how to implement this in a different manner: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are placing html content inside an HTML property it should be escaped. As mentioned by @Karolis do this:

```
<p class="related_articles" title="<?php echo htmlentities('<a href="'.the_field(related_articles_1_link).'" target="_blank">'.the_field(related_articles_1_title).'</a>'); ?>">Related Articles</p>
```

This should generate a tooltip with the link in it. If you see stuff like "& lt;a href="... & gt;" on the tooltip then the plugin is not unescaping html values. You could unescape the values but unfortunately javascript has no function. For this you can check out [php.js](http://phpjs.org/)
which provides php's functions in js but that seems kinda overkill. You could instead replace the troublesome characters like this:

```
<?php
// Generate complete tootltip content
$tootltipContent = '<a href="'.the_field(related_articles_link_1).'">'.the_field(related_articles_link_1).'</a>';
// Search for these
$search = array('<','>','"');
// And replace them with these
$replacements = array('@#','@#','\"'); 
$tooltipContent = str_replace($search,$replacements,$tooltipContent);
?>
<p class="related_articles" title="<?php echo $tooltipContent; ?>">Related Stuff</p>
```

Then look for the line in the plugin where the title is extracted from the element. (tip: on the plugin source code do a search for 'title'. There should be one place where the value is being extracted) It may look something like this tooltipContent = $(someVar).attr('title'); Now run the inverse replacement in js:

```
tooltipContent = tooltipContent.replace('@#','<').replace('#@','>').replace('\"','"');
```